# Nesting controllers and views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller in my Laravel project called `ImageController`.  This is a pretty basic CRUD controller.

When I access `/images/{id}` through my `ImageController@show` action, I want to also display comments.  However, I don't want to put the comment logic in my `ImageController`.  For this logic, I have created an `ImageCommentController`.

I'm not really sure how to go about this, but I'm trying to do something of this sort:

```
class ImageController extends BaseController {
    // methods ...

    public function show($id)
    {
        $images = // get images ...
        $this->layout->view = // images.show and imagescomment.index (using ImageCommentsController@index logic)
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this is vaguely phrased, let me know if it is and I'll try to make it more understandable.

Comment: Why don't you want to put the code in your `ImageController`? That's the point of a controller -- to gather data to pass to the view. I don't agree with the solution you've chosen below, because it seems like an unnecessary work-around.

Comment: I don't know exactly where all I would like to put comments so I want to decouple the comment logic from the `ImageController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a better solutions than using a Controller for displaying the comments is to use a class with a method renderComments() that basically does something like:

```
class Comments {
    public static renderComments($commentType = 'images')
    {
        $comments = Comments::where('comment_type', '=', $commentType)->get();
        return View::make('comments', $comments)->render();
    }
}
```

Then for example inside your image view:

```
...
{{ Comments::renderComments() }}
...
```